# Incorrect google-services.json is picked by com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4

Tags: android, firebase

My android app uses two firebase projects, one for development, and the other for the production.

I have placed the `google-services.json` of each firebase project in following directories.

Debug config:
<app_root>/app/google-services.json

Prod config:
<app_root>/app/src/release/google-services.json

I was using `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2` and this setup worked fine. When I am developing, the config at `<app_root>/app/google-services.json` was used and when generating a signed release bundle, the config at `<app_root>/app/src/release/google-services.json` was picked automatically by Android Studio.

I upgraded `google-services` version to 4.3.4 today, and it seems `<app_root>/app/src/release/google-services.json` is not picked when doing a signed release bundle build. It uses `<app_root>/app/google-services.json` instead.

Why is this? Can this be a bug in `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2`? or overriding configs at build types directory is not supported anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4` has changed the precedence of files, so that the `google-services.json` at `<app_root>/app/google-services.json` gets precedence over `<app_root>/app/src/release/google-services.json`, which was the other way around in version `4.3.2`.

I moved `<app_root>/app/google-services.json` to `<app_root>/app/src/debug/google-services.json`, which gives me the previous behavior.

Comment: If precedence of file is changed then it's more likely to be a bug than a change by design because usually specialized directories have precedence over general one in Android world. Moreover, standard document does not talk about such design change. An issue has been created for this on official repo. Follow https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/163 for official updates.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with the `<app_root>/app/src/debug/google-services.json` by changing `com.google.gms:google-services` from `4.3.3` to `4.3.4`. As a workarround I have **moved** the `<app_root>/app/google-services.json` to `<app_root>/app/src/release/google-services.json` and it works for me.